# Blocking a triggered Jenkins job until something *outside* Jenkins is done

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which starts a long-running process outside of Jenkins. The job itself is triggered by Gerrit.

If this job is triggered again while the long-running process is ongoing, I need to ensure that the job remains on the Jenkins queue until said process has completed. Effectively I want to ensure that the job never runs in parallel with itself, with the wrinkle that "the job" is really the Jenkins job plus the external long-running process.

I can't find any way to achieve this. The External Resource Dispatcher plugin seems like it could work, but every time I've configured it on our system, Jenkins got extremely unstable (refusing page loads for minutes on end, slave threads dying with NPEs). Everything else I can see, such as the Exclusions plugin, depend on Jenkins itself controlling the entirety of the job.

I've tried hacking something together with node labels - having the job depend on a label "can_run", assigning that label to master, and then having the job execute a Groovy script that removes that label from master. (Theoretically there would be another Jenkins job that adds the label back, which would be triggered by the end of the long-running process.) But it didn't work: if there were any queued instances of the job on Jenkins, they went ahead and started right away even though the label had been removed.

I don't know what else to try! Is there anything other than a required node label being missing which will cause Jenkins to *queue* the job if it is triggered, but not *start* it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the long-running process is triggered and your job return immediately, which make it an async process, right? I would suggest you handle the long-running process detection and waiting logic in your trigger process. Every time before you trigger the job, check if the long-running process is running, if not, trigger it.

Actually I am not quite getting what you are trying to do. Basically because of that long-running process, it is impossible for you to run 2 jobs in parallel. If this is true, make it non parallel job.